# How can my bot get username from specified member

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do I get an username from a member?
I want to create an information command that shows information about the mentioned user. And I need to get a username using a member, how do I do it?
This is currently what I have:

```
@client.command()
async def info(ctx):

    async with ctx.typing():

        time.sleep(1)

    info_embed = discord.Embed(title=ctx.message.author.name + '\'s Info', color=0x797d7f)

    info_embed.add_field(name='Username', value=ctx.message.author.user.name, inline=True)
    info_embed.add_field(name='Display Name', value=ctx.message.author.name, inline=True)
    info_embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    info_embed.set_footer(text=ctx.message.author.name + ' | ' + ctime(), icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)

    await ctx.send(embed=info_embed)
```

Comment: `ctx.message.author.name` is the users name and `ctx.message.author.display_name` is the users display name.

Comment: It doesn't work it has to be DisplayName#Id

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can mention or get an id of the user who you want info on, if you don't mention a user, it will respond with the user author info.

You can also add other information to this command, such as id, discriminator or join-date but I'll leave that up to you to figure out. If you need help feel free to ask!

```
@client.command()
async def info(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):
    if member == None:
        member = ctx.author

    async with ctx.typing():
        
        # import asyncio if you already have not
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

        info_embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{member.name}'s info", color=0x797d7f)

        info_embed.add_field(name='Username', value=(member.name), inline=True)
        info_embed.add_field(name='Display Name', value=(member.display_name), inline=True)
        info_embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
        info_embed.set_footer(text=ctx.message.author.name + ' | ' + ctime(), icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)

        await ctx.send(embed=info_embed)
```

Comment: you should also not use time.sleep, as this causes the "whole" bot to stop for the time being. Instead, you should use "await asyncio.sleep(1)"